# How to column values with another value In pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to replace some numbers in the numpy array with either a 1 or 0 with the numpy.where function, however I can only do it one at a time. For example, when I print out 'ones', it will only replace values that are more than 3.8845 with a 1, but the other values which are less than 3.8845 still remain the same, I want it such that the values less than 3.8845 are changed to 0 as well but I don't know how to do it. Do let me know if you know of a solution.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

happiness_2019 = pd.read_csv('2019.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(happiness_2019,columns=['Score']).to_numpy()
ones = np.where(df>3.8845,1,df)
zeros = np.where(df<3.8845,0,df)
zeros
```

Comment: Can you give an example for how '2019.csv' looks like?

Answer (score 1):

```
# generate dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Score':np.random.rand(10)*10})

# convert to 0,1:
df['Score'] = (df['Score']>3.8845).astype(int)
```

How it works:

`df['Score']>3.8845` is a boolean expression that evaluates to a `pd.Series` of `True` and `False`, depending on where the condition is met.

`.astype(int)` converts `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`, so we end up with a `pd.Series` of zeros and ones

Answer (score 0):

Try using this technique

```
ones = df>3.8845
zeros = df<3.8845
```

After that you can look into converting the boolean dataframe into 1's and 0's with something like this:

```
zeros = zeros.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an apply, then with a lambda function you can verify and add either 1 or 0.

```
df['Score'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x>yourvalue) else 0)
```

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

happiness_2019 = pd.read_csv('2019.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(happiness_2019,columns=['Score']).to_numpy()

df['Score'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x>3.8845) else 0)
df I did that and still nothing

Comment: The apply method goes over the Dataframe.
Erase the .to_numpy() and use it later, if you need the DataFrame as numpy:
happiness_2019 = pd.read_csv('2019.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(happiness_2019,columns=['Score'])
df['Score'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x>3.8845) else 0)
df_numpy = df.to_numpy()